# error: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false

Tags: socket.io, flutter

I am kind of new to flutter developments. Above error is getting to show up when `import 'package:socket_io/socket_io.dart';` from the package `socket_io: ^0.9.0+1`

i'm trying to connect node js back end socket to flutter app. I don't use a emulator but a Samsung Tab as a external device.

here is my client program

```
    void main() {
  var io = new Server();
    var nsp = io.of('/some');
    nsp.on('connection', (Socket client) {
      print('connection /some');
      client.on('msg', (data) {
        print('data from /some => $data');
        client.emit('fromServer', "ok 2");
      });
    });
      io.on('connection', (Socket client) {
        print('connection default namespace');
        client.on('msg', (data) {
          print('data from default => $data');
          client.emit('fromServer', "ok");
        });
      });
      io.listen(3000);

    // Dart client
    IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connect', (_) {
     print('connect');
     socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    });
    socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
    socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
    socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
  runApp(new MyApp());
  }
```

and this is pubspec.ymal

```
: chat_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  socket_io: ^0.9.0+1
  socket_io_client: ^0.9.1
  http: ^0.12.0
  reflectable: ^2.0.9


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

and this is my back end service which is work fine written in node

```
 const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var path = require('path');
var cors = require("cors");
users=[];
app.use(cors())
'use strict';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var iss = "Blitzkrieg Software";
var sub = "joe@user.org";
var aud = "http://blitzkriegsoftware.net";



const fs = require('fs');
var privateKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
var publicKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
var exp = 24;
var signOptions = {
    issuer : iss,
    subject: sub,
    audience: aud,
    expiresIn: exp,
    algorithm: "RS256"
};

var payload = { };

// Populate with fields and data
payload.field01 = "Data 01";
payload.field02 = "Data 02";
payload.field03 = "Data 03";
var token = jwt.sign(payload, publicKey, signOptions);
console.log("Token: " + token);
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
console.log("Docoded Header: " + JSON.stringify( decoded.header));
console.log("Docoded Payload: " +  JSON.stringify(decoded.payload));

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cors());
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

    res.render('index')
    res.status=600;

})





server = app.listen(3000,"0.0.0.0");




// app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
//     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); 
//     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
//     contents = fs.readFileSync("sliderImages.json", "utf8");
//     console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/sliderImages.json'));
//     res.end(contents);
//  });
const io= require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    var dbUrl = 'mongodb://brad:1234@localhost:27017/bawa'
    mongoose.connect(dbUrl ,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (err,db) => { 
        // db.collection("customers").insertOne({"first_name":"gahsat","last_name":"assdf"}, function(err, res) {
        //     if (err) throw err;
        //     console.log("1 document inserted");
        //     db.close();
        //   });

        //   db.collection("customers").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, first_name: 1, last_name: 1 } }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        //     if (err) throw err;
        //     console.log(result);
        //     db.close();
        //   });
        console.log('Db connected',err);
     })

    console.info('New user connected'+socket.id)

    //default username
    socket.userId = "Anonymous"

    //listen on change_username
    socket.on('change_userId', (data) => {
        console.info('change_userId: ' + data);
        socket.userId = data.userId
    })
    socket.on('register', (data) => {
        console.info('New user cregonnected '+socket.id)
        console.info('register: ' + data);
        socket.userId = data.userId
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
        console.info('change_userId: ' + data);
        socket.userId = data.userId
    })

    socket.on('send message', (data) => {
        console.info('New user sen '+socket.id)
        //var a=JSON.parse(data)
        console.info('messasge: ' + data["kk"]);
        io.sockets.emit('get user','sdfgsdfgsdf')
    })

    //listen on new_message
    socket.on('new_message', async (data) => {
        //broadcast the new message
        let chat = chatDb.chats.find(_chat => _chat.id === data.chatId);
        chat.dialog = [
            ...chat.dialog,
            data.message
        ];
        let userId = data.message.who;
        let contactId = data.contactId;
        const user = chatDb.user.find(_user => _user.id === userId);
        console.info('new_message User: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
        const contact = chatDb.user.find(_user => _user.id === contactId);
        console.info('new_message Contact: ' + JSON.stringify(contact));
        user.chatList.find(_contact => _contact.contactId === contactId).lastMessageTime = data.message.time;
        contact.chatList.find(_contact => _contact.contactId === userId).lastMessageTime = data.message.time;
        console.info('new_message: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        io.sockets.emit('new_message', {userId: userId, contactId: contactId, chatId: data.chatId, message: data.message});
    })

    //listen on typing
    socket.on('typing', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', {userId : socket.userId, chatId: data.chatId})
    })
});



console.log('Server Started')
```

I hope i couldn't find an answer why this happens and how to resolve..
please help

Comment: Please add the exact and full error output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `socket_io` is not compatible with Flutter. You can therefore not use it within a Flutter application.